# Reinstate hover rules after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am using the below script to hide/show my main nav menu items. You can see it live here: http://205.134.239.12/~artscr6/artscrush/#!

One part of my menu uses down arrows (represented using font awesome with the `<i>` tags) and when the user hovers over the menu item, the arrow appears. This works in the initial state, but once the user clicks one of the menu items to show the flyout, the hover effect no longer works to show the arrows.

What would I need to add to keep that hover effect happening, but still keep the current behavior as well?

```
/Remove the link elements from the main nav top level
$('.menuItem a').attr('href', '#!');

//Show the down arrows on hover
    $('menuItem').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('i').css('opacity', '1');
    })

//Once menu is clicked
$('.menuItem').click(function() {

    //Reset
    menuReset();

    //Find the correct flyout
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = item.substring(item.indexOf("_") + 1);
    var findFlyout = '#acFly_' + id;

    //Make this item active
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //Bumps the current down arrow down a bit and shows it
    $(this).find('i').css('opacity', '1');
    $(this).find('i').css('top', '7px');


    //Show the flyout
     event.stopPropagation(); //This prevents dom from overriding us
    $(findFlyout).toggle();

    //Prevent clicks on the current menu from hiding the flyout
    $(findFlyout).click(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
    })



})

//Hide the menu when the user clicks anywhere 
$(document).click( function(){
    menuReset();
})


function menuReset() {
    $('.flyMenu').hide();
    //Resets the down arrows to orig position and hidden
    $('.menuItem').find('i').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.menuItem').find('i').css('top', '0px');
    $('.menuItem').removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Show the down arrows on hover
    $('menuItem').hover(function() { // Shouldn't this be .menuItem instead?
        $(this).find('i').css('opacity', '1');
    })
```

Also, in the css file on the link you gave me I find the following:

```
#menu .ul .li:hover i{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I don't think ul and li are classes, so why is there a . ?

EDIT: Oh, I see now. You named your divs ul and li. :)

Comment: Excellent! That fixed it. I have CSS doing this action as well initially, and that's what was working, I just thought the js was working before the click. Thanks for your sharp eyes! :)

Comment: Here's some extra info about this subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Yes, I'm using them as classes for now because using `ul` `li` tags ran into some problems with styling inside of them. This is a first-go on the project and I'll be re-writing the code before launch to be more normalized.